# google drive api iOS example

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

Is there a working example of Google Drive API for iOS?
This example doesn't work - 
https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: I follow each step that is on the site and watched the video to see if i was missing a step since i get errors and he gets the same errors.  In the video at 13:45 there are 5 errors that come up.  I get those errors but don't know what step i messed up on to handle those errors.

I downloaded the google api files
my user header search path is to that folder /Source**
I added the correct frameworks (although there is a GTL.Framework that isn't added in the video)
I added the 3 files directly to my project
I updated the other links flags

Comment: After doing it 10 times, it works.  Really don't know why it works now and at this point don't care.

Comment: @user1664112 Do you know how upload images to drive?